# Regex match a mac address without semi-columns

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to understand why the below function is returning weird results

```
<?
$string = "001122334 001122334455 0011 0011223344556677";
preg_match_all('/([a-fA-F0-9]){12}/', $str, $matches);
?>
```

I don't get why the 001122334455 appears twice and why is the 5 5 doing there.
I am looking to find MAC Address without semi-columngs match

Output

```
Array
( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 001122334455
        [1] => 001122334455
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
    )
)
```

Comment: Use `preg_match_all('/\b[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\b/', $str, $matches)`, see [demo](https://3v4l.org/JfG99)

Comment: when using regex, the third argument (passed by reference) is set with [0] containing the whole string matched, and [1], [2], etc. containing the text matched by the capturing parenthesis. So here, it's normal you have twice your 001122334455 value (one for whole string, one for the parenthesis content, which is in your case the same thing)

Comment: however, that still does not explain the 5...

Comment: @Pierre See my answer explaining `5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex

- contains a [*repeated capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), `([a-fA-F0-9]){12}`, that is, a hex char is captured into a group, and then the value of the group is re-written 11 times more (all in all, 12 times), so the last hex char captured lands in the second matches subarray (in each match you get with your input string, it is `5`, thus, you have two `5`s in your second array).
- is not anchored on both sides, so it is found anywhere inside the string, so you get two matches, `001122334455` is matched and `001122334455` in `0011223344556677` is also matched.

Remove the capturing parentheses and use a whole word matching pattern like

```
# Word boundaries
preg_match_all('/\b[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\b/', $str, $matches)            
# Whitespace boundaries
preg_match_all('/(?<!\S)[a-fA-F0-9]{12}(?!\S)/', $str, $matches)   
# Hex char boundaries
preg_match_all('/(?<![a-fA-F0-9])[a-fA-F0-9]{12}(?![a-fA-F0-9])/', $str, $matches)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/cjmWV)

Comment: That was it; so dumb. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have to parse the space end of value.

```
$string = "001122334 001122334455 0011 0011223344556677";
preg_match_all('/([a-fA-F0-9]){12}\ /', $string, $matches);
```